# How to stop VBA execution if the no error occurs

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("B1").Select
    
Columns("B:B").Select

    Selection.Find(What:="Grand Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

a = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)

Range("B1").Select

On Error GoTo er

Columns("B:B").Select

    Selection.Find(What:="Opt Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate



b = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)


Range("B100").Value = "=IfError(" & a & "-" & b & ",0)"

Range("B100").Select
Selection.Copy

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Range("B100").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "New Total"


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "xyz"
ActiveWindow.Close (True)

Workbooks(vb).Activate

Next i

MsgBox "Files are ready"


er:

Range("B100").Value = "=" & a

Range("B100").Select
Selection.Copy

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Range("B100").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "New Total"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "xyz"
        
ActiveWindow.Close (True)

Workbooks(vb).Activate

Next i

MsgBox "Files are ready"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert `Exit Sub`:

```vb
MsgBox "Files are ready"
Exit Sub

er:
```